# Get Unique value from Series of elements in a column

Tags: pandas

How to get value counts for below given data in a column

### Ticket_No - COLUMN NAME

ABC10

ABC20

ABC30

XYZ11

XYZ12

IJK11

IJK22

I need count of total ABC,XYZ,IJK

for example, ABC 3, XYZ 2, IJK 2

```html
data.groupby('Ticket_No').size()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df.Ticket_No.str.findall('^[A-Za-z_]+').str[0].value_counts()

Out[513]:
ABC    3
XYZ    2
IJK    2
Name: Ticket_No, dtype: int64
```